# De\Serializing list of objects XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-deserialization

I have been tried to do deserialize and it doesn't work. Why it happen ? Im tring to deserialize list of object as I serialize list of object. Is it possible ? Im trying something but it doens't the correct way. Thanks on help.

My code :

in the main :

```
Serialize(lstObservers);

 public void Serialize(List<Observer> list)
        {
           XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Observer>));
            using ( TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter( @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\MapSample\bin\Debug\ListObserver.xml"))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, list);
            }  
        }

   private void DiserializeFunc()
        {
            var myDeserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Observer>));
        using (var myFileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\MapSample\bin\Debug\ListObserver.xml", FileMode.Open))
        {
            listObservers = (List<Observer>)myDeserializer.Deserialize(myFileStream);
        }

        }
```

the class observer :

```
    [Serializable()]
    public class Observer : MapObject
    {
        private int ID_Observer { get; set; }
        private double azimuth;
        private double Long;
        private double Lat;
        private double Lenght;
        private bool haveConnection;
        private bool DrawAzimuth;
        private XmlSerializer ser;

        /// <summary>
        /// C'tor
        /// </summary>
        public Observer(int ID_Observer = 0, double azimuth = 0, double Lat = 0, double Long = 0, double Lenght = 0, bool haveConnection = true, bool DrawAzimuth = true)
        {
            this.ID_Observer = ID_Observer;
            this.azimuth = azimuth;
            this.Long = Long;
            this.Lat = Lat;
            this.haveConnection = haveConnection;
            this.DrawAzimuth = DrawAzimuth;
            this.Lenght = Lenght;
        }

        public Observer()
        {
            ser = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
        }
}
```

**EDIT : my propose is to save list of objects.. if anyone have another idea i will be more than happy to learn. Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private fields don't serialize. Make properties that are public:

```
      [Serializable()]
  public class Observer : MapObject
  {

    private XmlSerializer ser;

    public int ID_Observer { get; set; }
    public double azimuth { get; set; }
    public double Long { get; set; }
    public double Lat { get; set; }
    public double Lenght { get; set; }
    public bool haveConnection { get; set; }
    public bool DrawAzimuth { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// C'tor
    /// </summary>
    public Observer(int ID_Observer = 0, double azimuth = 0, double Lat = 0, double Long = 0, double Lenght = 0, bool haveConnection = true, bool DrawAzimuth = true)
    {
      this.ID_Observer = ID_Observer;
      this.azimuth = azimuth;
      this.Long = Long;
      this.Lat = Lat;
      this.haveConnection = haveConnection;
      this.DrawAzimuth = DrawAzimuth;
      this.Lenght = Lenght;
    }

    public Observer()
    {
      ser = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: It is showing two observer objects, not one. XML must have a root node, you cannot just have an uncontained collection of elements. that is why they are within the ArrayOfObserver. You can change "ArrayOfObserver" to something you like better with attributes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks. When I do deserialize object it doesn't work. I'm eddited the code

Comment: What do you mean by "In the Main" ?

Comment: works for me. I add 3 default observers. See my edit with new image. Of course, I don't have MapObject class to inherit from, I don't know if that is causing you problems.

Comment: Yes dude thanks the serialize works great. Now i want to deserialize it. how to do it into an empty list of observers? I edit my deserialize function. Please take a look it fail excepetion : Cannot create instance of 'Window1' defined in assembly 'MapSample, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.  Error in markup file 'Window1.xaml' Line 1 Position 9.

Comment: XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Observer>));
      TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"...\ListObserver.xml");
      var obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
      reader.Close();

Comment: Never mind I edited the function, I success by myself. Thanks Crowcoded !! :) Good day.

Comment: Last question, there is any way to do this function general ? I mean to serialize any list<Object> and no specific <Observer> ?

Comment: You should be able to use Object in place of Observer in all your code as long as the object has a default, parameterless constructor.

Comment: ask a new question about generic object serialization.